# AngularJS: Where to Invoke Bootstrap 5 Tooltip and Popover methods via jQuery in an AngularJS App?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-5, popover

We have an AngularJS 1.8.2 application that needs to be upgraded to Bootstrap 5 to support Tooltips, Popovers and Modals. We had been using ui-bootstrap to support such popups. But, it is way more difficult to migrate ui-bootstrap to Bootstrap 5 than replacing ui-bootstrap with Bootstrap 5 jQuery invocations.

**1. Where best to invoke `$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`?**

I had the good fortune of getting Tooltips to work as follows:

```
<button id="genderHelpID"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-link text-dark d-inline icon icon-info ml-1 {{vm.infoIconSize}} p-0"
    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
    data-bs-placement="bottom"
    data-bs-html="true"
    title="{{vm.genderHelpHtml}}">
</button>
```

And invoking Bootstrap 5 like so:

```
public myPostLink(scope: any, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctrls: {} | any, transclude?: ng.ITranscludeFunction): void {
  this.myForm = (<any>scope)[this.formName];
 
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
}
```

The result is a Bootstrap 5 tooltip complete with arrow that obeys the properties set on the HTML element:

[image]

The myPostLink method is part of a directive that contains the tooltip.  If I adhere to this pattern, multiple components with tooltips displayed at the same time would call this redundantly.  I hoping someone can suggest a better place to invoke this method to minimize redundant invocations.

**2. Where to invoke $(...).popover{...} ?**

Here is an example in HTML:

```
<a id="groupPopover" class="btn btn-link text-dark d-inline icon icon-info ml-1 text-em-1-25 p-0"
     href=""
     data-bs-toggle="popover"
     data-bs-trigger="focus"
     data-bs-placement="top"
    data-bs-content="While we cannot guarantee this accommodation, but we'll do our best to bill you anyway.">
</a>
```

And here's how I initialize it:

```
public $postLink(): void {
    super.$postLink();
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
    var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
    });
    });
}
```

Is there a better way to make a popover work in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

We have a base controller class that all of our components inherit.  I added the following jQuery code when the base class activates:

```
protected onActivated(activationResults: any): void {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                const hasTooltipClassName: string = "has-tooltip";
                var $toolTips = $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]:not(.' + hasTooltipClassName + ')');
                $toolTips.each(function () {
                    var $e = $(this);
                    $e.tooltip();
                    $e.addClass(hasTooltipClassName);
                });
                const hasPopoverClassName: string = "has-popover";
                var popoverList = [];
                var $popOvers = $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]:not(.' + hasPopoverClassName + ')');
                $popOvers.each(function () {
                    var $e = $(this);
                    popoverList.push(new bootstrap.Popover(this));
                    $e.addClass(hasPopoverClassName);
                });
            });
        }
```